# Path autocompletion extension for VS Code

Tags: text-editor, programming, visual-studio-code

First off, I know that there are already [some](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense) [extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ionutvmi.path-autocomplete) which do path completion. I tested most of them and they are working OK, but I'm searching something more advanced like [this](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-paths) plugin for Atom.

It should be able to automatically show path suggestions depending on a "scope" and not just when I type `/` or `./`.

Comment: By path, you mean filesystem path, right? Should it also work with Windows-type paths?

Comment: Yes, I mean filesystem paths. No, It doesn't have to support Windows-type paths.